# In RSA, are e and d technically equivalent?

Tags: rsa, public-key, key-generation

In the process of finding RSA key pairs, we first find a *e* that is relatively prime to *φ(n)* (where *n = p × q*), and then find *d* such that *e × d mod φ(n) = 1*. Is *d* also relatively prime to *φ(n)*, or not necessarily?

In practice, *e* is usually chosen to be 3 or 65537, but if we choose *e* to be a large enough number, can *e* and *d* be used interchangeably?